# Count-min sketch

Tags: algorithms, counting

I don't understand the use case of count min sketch.
Based on *[Count–min sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count%E2%80%93min_sketch)*, it says "serves as a frequency table of events in a stream of data.".

If I know there are N types of events, why can't I just allocate an array of N slots or a hashmap to keep track of the event frequencies as the stream is ingested?

Am I right to say the use case is when N is unknown or N is so large that it is not possible to keep the entire frequency array/hashmap in memory?

Answer (score 3):

Sketches are data structures used in streaming algorithms. The idea is that while the stream is very long, the hardware processing it has limited memory. We want to be able to retain statistical information about the data without storing it completely.

You can find more information about sketching [here](https://www.sketchingbigdata.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the use case is $N$ so large that the entire table would not fit in the main memory. For example, imagine that every event is tied to an IPv6 address. IPv6 uses 128 bits for each address, so you would in principle need an array with $2^{128}$ elements.

Comment: Even IPv4 is too big in many cases. In addition, its worth it to note that in some cases we may be sampling from an infinitely large set (for example all finite length strings)

Comment: but i can still use a distributed hashmap right? Or is that not practical?